# Issues implementing a check and erase on VBA coding for sells control

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, barcode-scanner, interface-implementation

I am having issues being able to implement a new VBA code. I am really rusty with this coding form and trying to create some new solutions.

I have 3 sheets. One ( which eventually will become a interface) on which I use a barcode scannerto scan a code.
A second sheet which works as inventory.
A thris sheet which works as a sells records.

When I scan the barcode, if it does not exist on the inventory, a error message is shown.
I want also to check the sells sheet, Column A. If the barcode exist, a error message should be shown.
If if doesnt exist, it should then carry with the program.
I have manage to reach all the way to this last statemnet, but I dont manage to integrate the two codes together.

Code in Table 1, Scan

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C2")) Is Nothing Then
     
        Call receive
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Code in Macro 1

```
Sub receive()
Dim barcode As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim rown, lrow As Long
Dim qty As Long


barcode = Tabelle1.Cells(2, 3)
Tabelle2.Activate
'is there a barcode
If barcode = "" Then Exit Sub
If barcode <> "" Then

    Set rng = Tabelle2.Columns("A:A").Find(what:=barcode, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      ' send an error message if you do not find it
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Barcode nicht gefunden"
            GoTo ende
        Else
         'determine which row has the barcode
            rown = rng.Row
            
            If barcode = "" Then Exit Sub
            If barcode <> "" Then
            'add the value to the columns
                Tabelle2.Cells(rown, 8).Value = Tabelle2.Cells(rown, 8).Value
              'copy the description information
                Tabelle2.Range(Cells(rown, 2), Cells(rown, 7)).Copy
                Tabelle3.Activate
           'paste it on the lastrow of the scan sheet
                lrow = Tabelle3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Tabelle3.Cells(lrow, 2).PasteSpecial
           'enter the barcode and the barcode information
                Tabelle3.Cells(lrow, 1).Value = barcode
            'enter the date and time for when this happened
                Tabelle3.Cells(lrow, 8) = Date & "  " & Time
                Tabelle3.Cells(lrow, 8).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
                MsgBox "Registered"
                GoTo ende
            End If
           
         End If
    
End If
    
ende:
'turn off the marching ants
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Tabelle1.Activate

Tabelle1.Cells(2, 3).ClearContents

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("scan").Activate
Sheets("scan").Range("C2").Select '(and activate)
End Sub
```

Code Macro 2

```
Sub TestForDuplicates()
Dim rng As Range

'Store Range to search through
  Set rng = Range("A2:A3")

'Test Range for Duplicates
  If Evaluate(Replace("NOT(AND((COUNTIF(@,@)=1)))", "@", rng.Address)) = True Then
    MsgBox "Product already sold"

End Sub
```

I am having issues implementing the protocol of Macro 2 into Macro 1, so if first checks that the code is in the inventory, and if this is true, it checks that the code **IS NOT** on table 3 column A. If this is true, I will like it to continue with the copy paste of the data in inventory.

Another thing that I had in mind was that, after registering the data in sheet 3 Sells, that the data on Sheet 1 inventory change for not sold to sold(or got erased from the inventory), but after not being able to solve this issue, I got a little discouraged.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Quick note:  `Dim rown, lrow As Long`.  `rown` is defined as a Variant type here.  `Dim rown As Long, lrow As Long` to have both as Long.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding the solution after a while. I will post it in case it can help someone else.

```
  Sub receive()
    Dim barcode As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim rown, lrow As Long
    Dim qty As Long


    barcode = Tabelle1.Cells(2, 3)
    Tabelle2.Activate
    'is there a barcode?
    If barcode = "" Then Exit Sub
    If barcode <> "" Then

        Set rng = Tabelle2.Columns("A:A").Find(what:=barcode, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    ' send an error message if you do not find it
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Barcode nicht gefunden"
    ' send an error message if you do not find it
           
        Else
            Set rng3 = Tabelle3.Columns("A:A").Find(what:=barcode, _
                                                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                    searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    ' If found, Send error message
            If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Bereits verkauftes Produkt"
    'determine which row has the barcode
            Else
                rown = rng.Row

                If barcode = "" Then Exit Sub
                If barcode <> "" Then
    'add the value to the columns
                    Tabelle2.Cells(rown, 8).Value = Tabelle2.Cells(rown, 8).Value
    'copy the description information
                    Tabelle2.Range(Cells(rown, 2), Cells(rown, 7)).Copy
                    Tabelle3.Activate
    'paste it on the last row of the sells sheet
                    lrow = Tabelle3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    Tabelle3.Cells(lrow, 2).PasteSpecial
    'enter the barcode and the barcode information
                    Tabelle3.Cells(lrow, 1).Value = barcode
    'enter the date and time for when this happened
                    Tabelle3.Cells(lrow, 8) = Date & "  " & Time
                    Tabelle3.Cells(lrow, 8).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
                    MsgBox "Registered"
                End If

            End If
        End If

    End If
    'turn off the marching ants
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Tabelle1.Activate

    Tabelle1.Cells(2, 3).ClearContents

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("scan").Activate
    Sheets("scan").Range("C2").Select    '(and activate)
End Sub
```